# Woocommerce checkout page required checkbox error is showing error even when checkbox is not shown

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need a second required checkbox (similar to the existing "Terms" checkbox) on woocommerce checkout page. I need it to only show up when a specific product is in the cart. I have figured out this code sofar which works perfectly except one point:

The error message for "unchecked checkbox" is thrown also when the product is not in the cart and the checkbox is not shown.

I can see from the structure of the code that most likely what is wrong is that the code which throws the error-message is not inside the if-statement which checks whether the item is in the cart, I tried various ways to restructure this code, but I did not manage to make it work. Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```
/*Add custom text to checkout page if PDU subscription order is in the cart*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'wordimpress_custom_checkout_field', 10 );

function wordimpress_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    //Check if Book in Cart (UPDATE WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID)
    $book_in_cart = wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( 161042 );

    //Book is in cart so show additional fields
    if ( $book_in_cart === true ) {
        woocommerce_form_field( 'checkout_checkbox', array( // CSS ID
               'type'          => 'checkbox',
               'class'         => array('form-row mycheckbox'), // CSS Class
               'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
               'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
               'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
               'label'         => 'I have read and agree to the <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">subscription terms</a>', // Label and Link
            ));    
    }
}
        
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bt_add_subscription_checkbox_warning' ); 
//Alert box if not checked
function bt_add_subscription_checkbox_warning() {
    if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['checkout_checkbox'] ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'You must read and accept the subscription terms to start a monthly subscription.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

//Check if Conditional Product is In cart
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    //Check to see if user has product in cart
    global $woocommerce;
    $book_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
            //book is in cart!
            $book_in_cart = true;
        }
    }
    return $book_in_cart;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a day of sweating over this and trying virtually every possible combination I figured out the answer. I'm posting the complete code below for any future person that comes across this with the same question.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'wordimpress_custom_checkout_field', 10 );

function wordimpress_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $book_in_cart = wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( 161042 ); //product ID
    //Book is in cart so show additional fields
    if ( $book_in_cart === true ) {
        woocommerce_form_field( 'checkout_checkbox', array( // CSS ID
               'type'          => 'checkbox',
               'class'         => array('form-row mycheckbox'), // CSS Class
               'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
               'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
               'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
               'label'         => 'I have read and agree to the <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">subscription terms</a>', // Label and Link
            ));    
    }
}
        
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bt_add_subscription_checkbox_warning' ); 
    //Alert box if not checked
    function bt_add_subscription_checkbox_warning() {
    $book_in_cart = wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( 161042 );
    if ( ( $book_in_cart === true ) && ! (int) isset( $_POST['checkout_checkbox'] ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'You must read and accept the subscription terms to start a monthly subscription.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

//Check if Conditional Product is In cart
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $book_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
            //book is in cart!
            $book_in_cart = true;
        }
    }
    return $book_in_cart;
}
```